# C# WPF Cmb Text in Textfield with Thread

Tags: c#, wpf

I´m using the BusyIndicator in my GUI because I have to work with a database that the GUI don´t freeze meanwhile.

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    richSammelbemerkung.Document.Blocks.Clear();
    richSammelbemerkung.AppendText("Daten werden gesucht...");
    GUIData guiData = new GUIData();
    guiData = getInfoFromGUI();
    ZeichnungCollection zeichnungen = new ZeichnungCollection();
    BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    busyIndicator.IsBusy = true;
    worker.DoWork += (o, ea) =>
    {
        zeichnungen = searchDrawings(guiData);
    };
    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (o, ea) =>
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dataOutOfDb.ItemsSource = zeichnungen).Refresh()));
        busyIndicator.IsBusy = false;
        if (zeichnungen.Count == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Keine Daten gefunden. Eventuell Index überprüfen.", "Info");
        }
        richSammelbemerkung.Document.Blocks.Clear();
        dataOutOfDb.SelectedIndex = 0;
        Keyboard.Focus(dataOutOfDb);
    };

    busyIndicator.IsBusy = true;
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

It´s look like this.
Before I put the BusyIndicator into my GUI I just run the code and used the SelectionChanged of the Cmb to set the selected Text into a Textfield.
The problem I have now is, that when the SelectionChanged is fired it throws a Exception even if I used a IF to ask for elements.
So I went on with DataBinding like this:

```
Text="{Binding ElementName=cmbTag, Path=SelectedItem}"
```

Now when it doesn´t throw a exception or anything else.
BUT, I can´t set a new value in the Textfield because it automatically refreshes on what is selected in the Combobox.
So, has anyone an idea how I can set the selected value from the Cmb to the Textfield without using SelectionChanged or DataBinding, or even so that it doens´t throw a exception?

Comment: This is a primary use case for `async`/`await` introduced in C# 5.0/.NET 4.5.

Comment: So, what I should do to fix this issue? I just used the tutorial for the BusyIndocator with the Async.

Comment: What kind of exception is thrown on which line?

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the `BusyIndocator`.

The problem is that you want to access the UI from another thread. But any operation with the UI must be made from the UI-Thread.

In your example anything within the `DoWork` method (which runs in another thread) can not access the UI. You'll get an exception or Bindings won't work.

You can use a Dispatcher within the `DoWork` method to track the code back to the UI Thread, like this:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { 
   // this code will run in the UI Thread again
});
```

But I think it's more elegant to remove all UI manipulation from the DoWork Action or use the BackgroundWork's [ReportProgress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3zbdb1t(v=vs.110).aspx) Method for that.